# Refresh gallery on Android 7 downwards?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I can use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` as of SDK 2.2+.

After taking an image and saving it on the sd card, how can I trigger scanning of images in SDKs lower than 2.2 (2.1 downwards)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two [`MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) methods. Use the one available since API 1.

```
// available since API 1
scanFile (String path, String mimeType)  

// available since API 8
scanFile (Context context, String[] paths, String[] mimeTypes, MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener callback)
```

Comment: WOW thanks. Do you know how to get mimeType from the File object? It does not have getType method.

Comment: Use "image/*" mime type. Or if you have a concrete image type: "image/jpeg" or "image/png".

Comment: Hm, I have only one scanFile. That's why I didn't see it. Could this be a problem `android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8"`?

Comment: Found it. Another one is non-static.